# Python - list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python-3.x

new to python and for some reasons, I thought my code was good, but for some reasons I keep getting this error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
csv_path = os.path.join("Resources", "budget_data.csv")

with open(csv_path, newline="", encoding='utf-8') as budget_data:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(budget_data, delimiter=',')

    total_amount = 0

    for row in csv_reader:
        total_amount =  total_amount + int(row['profit/losses'])
```

Comment: I don't know the structure of your `budget_data.csv` file. But I believe converting your `list` into a `dictionary` will solve it. 
`csv_reader = dict(csv.reader(budget_data, delimiter=','))`

Comment: Python-3.x and Python-2.7 are essentially two different languages. Which of them exactly do you use?

Answer (score 4):

A `row` is a list of columns. It must be indexed with integer numbers.

If you want to use column names as indexes, you need a `csv.DictReader()` instead of a `csv.reader()`.

Comment: I'm using python 3. Thanks for your answer. it worked by using csv.DictReader